# BibTeX and writing reference entries manually

Tags: bibtex

Is it possible to use BibTeX and write some entries manually? Normally I have entries in .bib file having all the needed fields to create a reference.

I'd like to be able to add a new entry having only one string and that string would then be added to references exactly as I wrote it without any processing or formating.

Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't tested, but can't you do simply `@misc{testkey,note={{like you want it}},}`

Comment: Please provide an example of an entry consisting of one one string. Incidentally, how should this entry be sorted in relationship to the other entries: At the beginning, the end, or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B, that was exactly what I needed! Posted answer and addressed you. Mico, it should be sorted just like other references. I'm using number system so in order of appearance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Johannes_B gave the wanted answer in comments above. I'll put it here:

```
 @misc{testkey,note={My own reference text}}
```

This achieves exactly what I want: the ability to write references manually but still maintain the ability to sort them properly (using number reference system).

(The reason is to be able to not spend too much time configuring different presets when I can achieve a proper reference in a fraction of time by writing it myself manually.)